# Is $S = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3: \sqrt{(x^2+y^2)} \leq z \leq 1\}$ bounded, compact and/or path connected?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I know if it is bounded then it is definitely compact. So how to prove it is bounded or path-connected? 
So far I have only done these in 2 dimensions so I'm not sure where to start here.

Answer (score 1):

You have $||x,y,z|| \leq ||x,y,0|| + |z| \leq 2$, so it is bounded.

It’s a cone. A point $(x,y,z)$ can be linked to $0$ by $(tx,ty,tz)$, $t\in [0,1]$.